# Inequality Problem using the A.M. - G.M. inequality

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I request everyone to please post the solution to this problem using the **A.M. - G.M. Inequality**. The problem is as follows -

---

**Problem -**

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers smaller than $1$ such that $abc=0.5$
Prove that
$$b(c^2+a^2+1)+c(a^2+b^2+1)+a(b^2+c^2+1)-3\geq 2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$$

---

**My progress -** 
I tried using the A.M. - G.M. on all the brackets and then equating the value using the value of $abc$ but I was not able to get the correct answer. Ii request someone to please give me a hint to this problem.

Comment: I request someone to please share the answer to this question ...

Comment: Must you use AM-GM? The condition that $0 < a \leq 1$ makes it less likely that AM-GM will be successful.

Comment: Ok ... so what can we use here then ?

Comment: Other approaches. Given that the equality condition includes $(1,1, .5)$, I suggest using Lagrange multiplier . For classical inequality approaches, you have to be a bit more creative with the bounding.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for helping